# Convert 2D array to assigned key Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
array = [
    ["Work", 11.0],
    ["Eat", 2.0],
    ["Commute", 2.0],
    ["Watch Tv", 2.0],
    ["Sleep", 7.0]
];
```

May I know how to convert the array to object:

```
var data = [{
        "Task": "Work",
        "Hour": 11.0
    },
    {
        "Task": "Eat",
        "Hour": 2.0
    }, {
        "Task": "Commute",
        "Hour": 2.0
    }, {
        "Task": "Watch Tv",
        "Hour": 2.0
    }, {
        "Task": "Sleep",
        "Hour": 7.0
    },
]
```

Comment: `const data = []; array.forEach(a=>{ data.push({task:a[0], hour:a[1]}); });`. I kept `task` and `hour` lowercase, like you should *(convention)*.

Answer (score -1):

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will create a new array based on a transformation of each element.  The transformation you should apply is to create an object where the `Task` property is element [0] of the array item and the `Hour` property is the element [1] of the array item.

```js
array = [
  ["Work", 11.0],
  ["Eat", 2.0],
  ["Commute", 2.0],
  ["Watch Tv", 2.0],
  ["Sleep", 7.0]
];

result = array.map(e => ({ Task: e[0], Hour: e[1] }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Could the down-voter please explain why this was down-voted so that I may improve the answer?